# Rsync Copies Whole Directory Content Instead of Single File

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, rsync

I am having trouble with an rsync command that is doing extra work that I do not expect. The command below is supposed to only rsync a *single* file to a destination server's directory.

However, it's copying extra files from the `${OUT_DIR}/make` directory into the destination even though I attempt to `--exclude` all other files from that directory.

How do I make rsync only copy the target file?

```
eval rsync -azu --delete \
--include ${OUT_DIR}/make/file.mk \
--exclude ${OUT_DIR}/make \
${OUT_DIR}/make/file.mk
${DEST_USER}@${DEST_SVR}:$OUT_DIR_DEST/make
```

I have already tried to remove "extra" options, but I run into errors doing that, so trying to get the command above working seemed like the best course of action. But here's what I get when I try to change it up:

```
eval rsync \
${OUT_DIR}/make/file.mk
${DEST_USER}@${DEST_SVR}:$OUT_DIR_DEST/make

Incompatible options specified for inc-recursive connection.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at compat.c(268) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Removing the --delete related options:

```
eval rsync -azu
${OUT_DIR}/make/file.mk
${DEST_USER}@${DEST_SVR}:$OUT_DIR_DEST/make

opening connection using: ssh -x -i ... rsync --server -vvulogDtprze.iLs . 

$OUT_DIR_DEST/make 
note: iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-8") succeeded.
(Client) Protocol versions: remote=30, negotiated=30
sending incremental file list
[sender] make_file(file.mk,*,0)
[sender] flist start=1, used=1, low=0, high=0
[sender] i=1 /OUTDIR/path file.mk mode=0100664 len=91 uid=300 gid=301 flags=5
send_file_list done
file list sent
send_files starting
ERROR: buffer overflow in recv_rules [receiver]
rsync error: error allocating core memory buffers (code 22) at util.c(123) [receiver=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
_exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=600): entered
_exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=600): about to call exit(12)
```

Most of the google searching I have done, has not lead to any obvious solutions to either problem.

Comment: Why do you believe you need all those arguments?

Comment: If I remove the --delete option I get an error stating "ERROR: buffer overflow in recv_rules". If I set it up with no args I get the error "Incompatible options specified for inc-recursive connection"

Comment: It's not that I "believe" that I need them. I want to get rid of them, however, doing so just leads to more problems. See the updated description above...

Comment: What does `$OUT_DIR` contain?

Comment: A canonical path to a local directory and $OUT_DIR_DEST is a different  canonical path to a remote directory

Comment: Read the whole description...

Comment: Backtick evaluation of `eval` of a command that doesn't look like it needs either of those??!?

Comment: Have you tried `rsync -azu ${OUT_DIR}/make/file.mk ${DEST_USER}@${DEST_SVR}:$OUT_DIR_DEST/make/`?

Comment: There are no backticks in the actual code. That's probably a mistake I made when I typed in the decription

Comment: @alvits yes the result is the same as one of the examples above with: ERROR: buffer overflow in recv_rules

Comment: This `rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]` seems like the login is getting interrupted. Try disabling `.bashrc` on the remote and test if `rsync` works. If it works, then investigate which lines in `.bashrc` is offending.

Comment: @alvits I removed the .bashrc under the user account for the remote side. It had no effect. I am wondering if it is an SSH issue, but the connection seems fine. I will update the description with a more verbose output from rsync

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving out the `eval` business as whatever extra expansions are in there are not clear, but I can show you what the rsync is supposed to look like. If you're using bash or zsh then you can do `set -x` and it will show you what commands it runs *really* look like after variable expansion.

The simplest solution is like this:

```
rsync -azu \
   /local/path/to/make/file.mk \
   user@server:/remote/path/to/make/
```

If you really want to use include/exclude rules (good if there's more than one include, maybe) then do it like this:

```
rsync -azu \
   --include=file.mk \
   --exclude='*' \
   /local/path/to/make/ \
   user@server:/remote/path/to/make/
```

The `--include` patterns are relative to the root of the source directory, so if you say `--include=/local/path/to/make/file.mk` then that pattern will only match a file called `/local/path/to/make/local/path/to/make/file.mk`, which is clearly not what you meant.

The `--exclude` rule works the same way, so basically you told it to exclude something that did not exist, so nothing got excluded. `--exclude='*'` means exclude everything (that was not already explicitly included), so you don't get errors like that.

You can change those rules by using the `--relative` option. That might make your original command work, I think, but it will create the file on the remote system here: `/remote/path/to/make/local/path/to/make/file.mk`

However you do it, the include rules need to come before the exclude rules: rsync uses the *first* rule that matches any given file or directory.

---

The error message you posted suggests the remote machine has run out of memory:

```
ERROR: buffer overflow in recv_rules [receiver]
rsync error: error allocating core memory buffers (code 22) at util.c(123) [receiver=3.0.6]
```

Memory usage was greatly improved in 3.0, but you seem to have 3.0.6 so presumably that's not something you can fix. Trying a new version (I have 3.1.2) might not be a bad plan.

If there's a lot of files under that folder (all but one excluded), then you might be able to save memory by avoiding the recursive option:

```
rsync -ptgo -zu \
   /local/path/to/make/file.mk \
   user@server:/remote/path/to/make/
```

All I've done is replaced `-a` with the equivalent `-rlptgoD` and then removed the unnecessary options, especially `-r`.

If all else fails you could try adding a swapfile on that machine.

Comment: Great explanation. I think this should work just fine, but I am still getting an error that is stopping the transfer `ERROR: buffer overflow in recv_rules [receiver]`. I think there is something wrong with SSH or the rsync between the two machines. Rsync and SSH versions are the same on each side though, so I'm not sure what could cause the recv_rules issue.

Comment: It looks like your remote machine may have run out of RAM?

Comment: I don't think so. I think it has to do with this particular line on the server side: `rsync --server -logDtprze.iLs --delete . $ROOTDIR`. I think the sender and receiver do not agree on the command being sent because of this receiver rule.

Comment: Still, it might be worth updating to a newer rsync

Comment: I wish it was that simple. Both sides are already using the latest 3.0.6 and negotiate the same protocol=30 when they connect.

Comment: 3.0.6 is from 2009

Comment: My mistake. I misread the rsync documentation. The most recently documented on I read was only for 3.06. Maybe an update is in order!